# How to write a function that takes a list of strings as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to create a function that takes a list of strings as a parameter, joins them together into a single string with each element separated by a comma, and returns the result. For example, if the array `[“asdf”, “jkl”, “zxc”]` is passed into the function, it will return a string `“asdf, jkl, zxc”`.

In C#, my function signature look like this:

```
string MySolution(string[] inputStrings)

{
  List<string> cities = new List<string>();
        cities.Add("New York");
        cities.Add("Mumbai");
        cities.Add("Berlin");
        cities.Add("Istanbul");

        string line = string.Join(",", cities.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

--I'm just having problems when it comes to having a user input where in a user will enter values, not the static as shown in the code. I will appreciate any suggestions or answers with regards to that. This also reserves as a test in the company that I'm applying for.

Comment: Are you looking for `string.Join`? e.g. `return string.Join(", ", inputStrings);`

Comment: Yes. I want to create a function that takes a list of string as a parameter and it must work for any array passed into it

Comment: @Aries that's what `String.Join` does. You don't need to create a new one. Check [its source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,84) to see how it handles any collection or variable argument lists

Comment: *Currying* the method though is very useful. You could create your own eg JoinComma as  `public static string JoinComma(IEnumerable<string> items)=>String.Join(",",items);` or using a local functions `string commaJoins(IEnumerable<string> items)=>String.Joins(",",items);`. Or you could use similar syntax to create a `Func<IEnumerable<string>,string> commaJoiner= items=>String.Join(",",items);`

Or

Comment: @Aries you can generalize this by creating a function that takes a separator and returns a `Func<IEnumerable...`, eg `Func<IEnumerable<string>,string> curryJoiner(string sep){ Func<IEnumerable<string>,string> myJoiner= items=>String.Join(sep,items); return myJoiner;}`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a method. You've already got:

```
string myJoinedString = String.Join(",", myStrings);
```

[MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

There is no reason to wrap `String.Join` in a method here. The additional layer is nothing but a hollow wrapper. Unless you want to start adding additional logic (error handling, custom separator logic, ...), but that's not part of your current question.